# CSS List: Replacing Bullet with Image and Adding Hover

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list that looks like the following:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="test.html">Item 1<li>
<li><a href="test2.html">Item 2</li>
<li><a href="test3.html">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want the bullet that appears to the left of each list item to be replaced by a right-facing triangle. The triangle, along with the text beside it, should change color on hover.

CSS can produce a triangle, but it appears choppy at smaller sizes. Therefore, I'm just looking for code that will allow me to edit the link location of two different triangle images.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your HTML is invalid (You need to close the anchor tags).

You can change the bullet image by using the `list-style-image` CSS property

```
ul { list-style-image: url('url-of-bullet1.png'); }
```

and you can change it on hover the same way, but by using the hover selector so it's only applied to the item the cursor is on:

```
ul li:hover { list-style-image: url('url-of-bullet2.png'); }
```

As for changing the text color, you can change it for the anchor elements by using the hover selector on the list items, like this:

```
ul li:hover a { color: #f00; }
```

**[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HequH/)**

Comment: This works for a simple list, but mine is a bit different. Here is the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/HequH/3/

Comment: Each list item has a dashed border below it and changes color on hover.  I want those same things to apply to the bullet area, with the bullet changing to a square on hover.

Comment: That will be a little bit tricky, but it's still possible. Use `list-style-position: inside;` in your `ul` style, change the `display` property for anchors to `display-block` and make their width less than 100% (You'll probably need to use something like `calc(100% - [width of the bullet])`), and apply the background color hover effect to the `li` elements instead of the anchors.